# perf: why don't I have "syscall" counters?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, perf

There are apparently some counters in Linux `perf` like `syscall:sys_enter_select`, but on my system `perf list` does not show any of them

Evidence that other people do have these counters is here: http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2014-07-03/perf-counting.html

If I run `perf top -e 'syscalls:sys_enter_*'` it says:

```
Can't open event dir: Permission denied
invalid or unsupported event: 'syscalls:sys_enter_*'
```

Other event types (the ones in `perf list`) work fine.

What do I need to do to access syscall counters in `perf`?  I'm using Linux kernel and perf version 3.10 on x86_64.

Comment: Can you provide `uname -a`?

Comment: "Permission denied".  Are you running as root or an ordinary user?  What groups is your user a member of?  And have you considered a kernel update?  Lots of security bugs fixed in the last year and a half.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Aha, it's because I'm not running as root!  If I run `sudo perf list` I can see the syscall counters.  I expected I'd be able to use those counters without running as root so long as I only wanted to inspect my own processes (that's how other counters work), but I guess not.  If you like, add an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I don't feel I can write a good answer to this, since I don't have a place to test, and can't authoritatively state whether root is required in all cases or not.

Comment: @BenVoigt: No problem, I'll answer myself.  Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some `perf` counters, including all the `syscall` ones, are only available to the root user.  `sudo perf list` will show all the counters, including `syscall` ones assuming the kernel is built with `CONFIG_HAVE_SYSCALL_TRACEPOINTS` (see Grisha Levit's answer regarding that).

So, to make `perf top -e 'syscalls:sys_enter_*'` work, run it under `sudo`--even if you do not need `sudo` for other counters like `cycles`.

Answer (score 3):

You must have an old version of `perf` to go with your crusty old 3.10 kernel.

**On a modern system** (x86-64 Arch Linux with Linux 4.15.8-1-ARCH, and a matching version of `perf`), **`perf` answers this question for you**:

```
$ perf stat -e 'syscalls:sys_enter_*stat*' ls -l
event syntax error: 'syscalls:sys_enter_*stat*'
                     \___ can't access trace events

Error:  No permissions to read /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/syscalls/sys_enter_*stat*
Hint:   Try 'sudo mount -o remount,mode=755 /sys/kernel/debug/tracing'

Run 'perf list' for a list of valid events
...


$ ll /sys/kernel/debug/ -d
drwx------ 33 root root 0 Mar 14 00:02 /sys/kernel/debug/
```

Interesting that you could make it world-readable, similar to how you can put `kernel.perf_event_paranoid = 0` and `kernel.yama.ptrace_scope = 0` in `/etc/sysctl.d/99-local.conf` for convenient debugging / tracing / profiling on a single-user desktop without using `root` all the time.

Comment: Only in the Linux world is a 1.5 year old kernel too old to be considered acceptable.  :)  Thanks for the tip about the bleeding edge.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: [Linux 3.10 was released 2013 Jun 30](https://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_3.10), which is about 5 years ago.  I already assumed you were running a version of it with distro patches for security updates and probably some features (especially drivers), but non-essential stuff like `perf` is probably still 5 years old.  But note that you question just says 3.10, not RHEL 3.10-whatever or something.  Anyway, I don't how recent a feature this new warning message is, so the snark about crusty old versions may have been unwarranted :P

Comment: In addition to the files, you need `kernel.perf_event_paranoid = -1` to run `perf top ...`, `perf stat` may be fine with a higher level. Also note that it can be a bit tricky to set the permissions, especially if you want to use fine-grained control.

Answer (score 2):

These will be missing if the kernel was not built with `CONFIG_HAVE_SYSCALL_TRACEPOINTS`.

You can check like so:

```
# grep TRACEPOINTS "/boot/config-$(uname -r)"
CONFIG_TRACEPOINTS=y
CONFIG_HAVE_SYSCALL_TRACEPOINTS=y
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but my system has those both set to `y`.

Comment: You may also need `CONFIG_FTRACE_SYSCALLS=y`.